# Huawei Mercury stuck in boot loop

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, boot-loop

about 4 weeks ago, i was developing a paranoidandroid rom for my huawei mercury. well, after the download, i needed to unzip the .zip file (using the base/port method). well, that was taking WAY to long, so, i decided to just flash the rom to my phone. well that didnt go so well. ever since then my device has been stuck in what i beleive to be is a boot-loop. i can access CWM-based recovery version 5.0.2.7 and DownloadMode (the screen you get while combining power and both voluume rockers, giving you access to the /image folder). i am not getting the blue screen of death, just the stupid huawei logo. if anyone can help me, and beleive me, 4 weeks of google can get tiring, can help me fix this, i would be soo happy. Thank-You much.
--Daniel

Comment: Try flashing the stock ROM for your phone. That will usually fix things. Let me know if it works so I can add it as answer. :)

Comment: triied. stays stuck :`( is there any way to fix thhis

Comment: Try it again and again. Sometimes I've had to flash more than 3 times before it succeeds.

Comment: ok, so just try it like 5 times, and if that doesnt work, ill tell you?

Comment: Yep. Try it. :)

Comment: it didnt work :,( any other ideas